# What is the Android equivalent of iOS MDM for VPN configuration?

Tags: android, vpn, mdm

I want to configure an always-on VPN for Android. I want this to happen automatically, by loading a web page or installing an app, but not by asking a user to type hostnames and so on into a settings UI. (A scenario might be a new employee with their own phone, who wishes to have convenient access to the corporate VPN.) I am familiar with how this can be done on iOS, by pointing a phone at an MDM server and downloading a configuration profile that contains the relevant VPN configuration, and want to do something comparable on Android.

Other answers refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html, but it does not mention VPNs. I suppose I could read the source to the relevant parts of WS02, but I’d prefer to start reading the appropriate Android documentation instead. Is there anything comparable to the *MDM Protocol Reference*?

Comment: There is no VPN support in WSO2 for Android.